# Fabricjs extend class

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I've created a custom class with fabric.js

```
var Container = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

    type: 'Container',
    initialize: function(options) {

        this.placedColor = 'rgba(211,211,211, 1)';
        this.virtualModeColor = 'rgba(211,211,211, 0.5)';

        this.setToVirtualMode();

        options || (options = { });
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
        this.set({
            label : options.label || '',
            'top' : options.top || 0,
            'left':  options.left || 0,
            'height' : options.height || 50,
            'fill' : options.fill || this.backgroundColor
        });
        self = this;
    },

    /**
     *@description set render mode to virtual
     */
    setToVirtualMode : function () {
        this.isInVirtualMode = true;
        this.backgroundColor = this.virtualModeColor;
    },

    /**
     * @description set render mode to placement
     */
    setToPlacementMode : function(){
        this.isInVirtualMode = false;
        this.backgroundColor = this.placedColor;
    },

    /**
     * @description toggle virtual mode on and off
     */
    toggleVirtualMode : function(){

        if (this.isInVirtualMode){
            this.setToPlacementMode();
        }else{
            this.setToVirtualMode();
        }
        this.set('fill', this.backgroundColor);
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    }
});
```

But when I create a new object Container and add it to canvas the object appears but it's not clickable. I have an event handle on my canvas that handles object:selected event but the e.target is never populated with the reference to Container object.

How to get working events on Container object?

Answer (score 0):

i do not see any problem with your class.
Be sure to add it to fabric object instead of declaring it as a standard variable

Check the console.log for e.target working correctly.

```js
fabric.Container = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

    type: 'Container',
    initialize: function(options) {

        this.placedColor = 'rgba(211,211,211, 1)';
        this.virtualModeColor = 'rgba(211,211,211, 0.5)';

        this.setToVirtualMode();

        options || (options = { });
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
        this.set({
            label : options.label || '',
            'top' : options.top || 0,
            'left':  options.left || 0,
            'height' : options.height || 50,
            'fill' : options.fill || this.backgroundColor
        });
        self = this;
    },

    /**
     *@description set render mode to virtual
     */
    setToVirtualMode : function () {
        this.isInVirtualMode = true;
        this.backgroundColor = this.virtualModeColor;
    },

    /**
     * @description set render mode to placement
     */
    setToPlacementMode : function(){
        this.isInVirtualMode = false;
        this.backgroundColor = this.placedColor;
    },

    /**
     * @description toggle virtual mode on and off
     */
    toggleVirtualMode : function(){

        if (this.isInVirtualMode){
            this.setToPlacementMode();
        }else{
            this.setToVirtualMode();
        }
        this.set('fill', this.backgroundColor);
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    }
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");
canvas.add(new fabric.Container({label: 'aasdasd', top: 10, left: 10, height: 60, width:200}));
canvas.on('object:selected', function(e) { console.log(e.target); });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js" ></script>
<canvas id="canvas2" width=500 height=500 ></canvas>
```

Comment: I found the problem. When you add it to canvas and change top and left values and then call canvas.renderAll() the controls of the object get lost and all the events are not fired.

Comment: @j-d Make sure you set object's LEFT or TOP properties via method `set()`. It means: `myObjectCreated.set('left', 250);` This way Fabric recalculates object's position and also position where it listens for mouse events. If you just set it like this: `myObjectCreated.left = 250` you need to call `myObjectCreated.setCoords()` afterwards to recalculate it manually.